# Find the Probability that the Largest Outcome of $3$ Fair Die Throws is a $3$

Tags: probability

> A fair die is thrown 3 times. Find the probability  that the largest outcome of the three throws is a 3.

I understand that the problem isn't as simple as $ \frac{3^3}{6^3}=1/8$, being the answer. That would mean getting any of the values from $1-3$ for all of the throws is favorable, which includes series of throws that do not even have $3$ as an outcome.

What's the solution to ensure that there is at least one throw with $3$ as the outcome, with the $2$ other throws being anywhere from $1-3$?

Comment: By brute force, I counted a total of $19$ favourable outcomes to a total of $216$ possible outcomes, which means the probability is $\frac{19}{216}=8.7\overline{962}\%$.  Are you provided an answer to compare this with?

Comment: Equivalent problem:  using the digits $1$ through $6$ to create a $3$ digit number, what is the probability that you create a number that contains the digit $3$ given that the number cannot include the digits $4$ through $6$?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** A result which has at all dice showing numbers at most $3$ which has at least one $3$ present is precisely a result which has all dice showing numbers at most $3$ which is not a result which has all dice showing numbers at most $2$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

If $X$ denotes the largest outcome then:$$\{X=3\}\cup\{X\leq 2\}=\{X\leq 3\}$$
Moreover the events on LHS are disjoint so that: $$P(X=3)+P(X\leq 2)=P(X\leq 3)$$

Answer (score 1):

The probability can be found by
$$P(\textrm{highest value is }3)=\frac{n(\textrm{one die is 3, the rest are 1 or 2}) +n(\textrm{two dice are 3, the other is 1 or 2}) + n(\textrm{all dice are 3)} }{n(\textrm{outcomes from three dice})}\\
=\frac{\binom31\cdot\binom21\cdot\binom21+\binom32\cdot\binom21+\binom33}{6^3}=\frac{12+6+1}{216}=\frac{19}{216}
$$

Answer (score 0):

As the maximum number thrown is $3$, so $4,5,6$ cannot be any outcome.

First count the number of cases when all the three dice are showing a number from the set $\{1,2,3\}={{3}^{3}}=27$

Then count the number of cases when all the three dice are showing a number from the set $\{1,2\}={{2}^{3}}=8$

Number of ways when at least one the dice is showing a number $3$ is $27-8=19$

Required Probability $=\frac{19}{27}$